# react video player full screen button hide not working on firefox

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented react video player and removed the full-screen button using CSS. It is working fine in the chrome and edge browsers but not working for the firefox browser. I have tried to fix it and found out that the control appearance is also different in firefox.
Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```
<ReactPlayer
 className='player'
 url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv11L-ZfrSg&ab_channel=8KVIDEOSULTRAHD'
 width="100%"
 height="100%"
 playing={true}
 controls={true}
 muted={true}
 config={{
 file: {
 attributes: {
 controlsList: 'nofullscreen'
 }
 }
 }}
 />
```

here is the CSS code

```
.player {
      video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
        display: none;
      }

      video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
        display: none;
      }

      video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
        display: none;
      }

      video::-webkit-media-controls-defaultsize-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```